# GStreamer hardware-accelerated video encoding on PC

Tags: encoding, gstreamer

I am trying to encode and containerize a 4K video using GStreamer. There are plenty of built-in plugins, but is there a plugin that takes advantage of my graphics card? I have an NVIDIA GeForce GTX480. I have read that NVIDIA exposes a VDPAU API, but are there plugins that take advantage of this?

Answer (score 1):

There is [VA API](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Playback+tutorial+8%3A+Hardware-accelerated+video+decoding) for this.
You have to either compile the vaapi elements from [source](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-vaapi) or if you are for example on Ubuntu there are binary packages for that (check `aptitude search vaapi`). I am sure there are means to install that on other OS.

I am not sure if nvidia is supported but on intel GPU things should work (if you can get some PC with i7 or so)

This is some [random pipe](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-media-sdk/topic/599911) with x264:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/ramdisk/bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normal.mp4 ! qtdemux ! vaapidecode ! vaapiencode_h264 ! video/x-h264,profile=high ! qtmux ! filesink location=/ramdisk/tmp.mov
```

UPDATE:

I found some [vpdau](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/tree/sys/vdpau) element in that first link on VA API.. I wonder if thats for Nvidia or what..